# How to find out when you and a friend became friends on facebook using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any Facebook Graph API call that will return a date when me and other friend became friends on Facebook?
And if there is no direct call - how can i figure this out using the Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API call for that. There is the Social Context, but it´s only for getting mutual friends and stuff: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.2

Comment: I tried Social Context before, but as you said - i cant figure friendship date from that..

Comment: yeah, i just added it because it may be the closest thing, but there is no api call for what you want, i am sure.